# Using jquery to check if element has class constantly

Tags: jquery, javascript

I'm using stickyJS to create a sticky header with my wordpress website. I have enqueued the scripts properly and the sticky is working perfectly.

What I am trying to achieve is to constantly check if the nav element that I have set up for the sticky has a class called "is-sticky" and if so change some of the CSS.

Here is the code that I have already:

```
function stickyInit($)
{
$("#site-navigation").sticky({topSpacing:0});

window.setInterval(check_sticky,500);

function check_sticky(){
    if($("#site-navigation-sticky-wrapper").hasClass("is-sticky")){
        console.log ("Do Something");
    }
}
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
stickyInit($);
});
```

This is all the code in the file that I have enqueued to set the nav as sticky.

As you can see I have used setInterval to try and create a loop to constantly test the "#site-navigation-sticky-wrapper" element to see if it has the class mentioned above.

This code works and I get the message in firebug console, but I only ever get it once instead of repeatedly.

So my question is, how do I constantly test this element to see if it has the class "is-sticky" so I can alternate the nav css when it does?

Also when the class "is-sticky" isnt set on the element (after I have scrolled back to the top) how do I set the nav back to its original position? Or will it just do that anyway?

Comment: Why do you use setInterval and not scroll event to do this? And most important... how is your question connected to WordPress?

Comment: To be honset ive not heard of the scroll event before, ill look into. And because im trying to perfom the on a wordpress website like i said up top, i thought i should post here as it is on a wordpress site and there could be some conflicts or bugs im missing in regards to wordpress

Comment: Here is a link to scroll event api docs: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/ I'm pretty sure it's js matter - WP has no do with this :)

Comment: Shall i reask it in stack overflow? or leave it here? Do you know im getting the issues i am? Thanks

Comment: I see where you were coming from with the scroll function but i dont think it's what i need. I simmple just need to constantly check of an element has a class or not and if it suddenly does it changes some CSS, thats all. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GW679/) - it fires repeatedly when the 'is-sticky' class is active & the nav position is automatically restored to its former state when you scroll to the stop.

```
// Your code
function stickyInit($){

    $("#site-navigation").sticky({topSpacing:0});

        function check_sticky(){
            if ( $("#site-navigation-sticky-wrapper").hasClass("is-sticky") ) {
                console.log ("Do Something");
            }
        }

    window.setInterval(check_sticky,500);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    stickyInit($);

});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, as far as i can see what you have done is moved the position of the setInterval from before to after the function being called by it. This is having the same effect as i had before, in the console i should be gettingthe string "Do Something" come up every half second, but instead i get it once and thats it. Any more suggestions? Thanks again

Comment: @TomBurman It is firing multiple times, the console is just collapsing duplicate console.log messages. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/GW679/1/

Comment: I should probably add that best practise would be to have it fire only once and again when it's actually at the top, but if it's what you want.. the code works fine.